# to find volume of spherical tetrahedron and triangle area

Tags: spherical-geometry

I have two question though they are different in some way

1. Could any one tell me how to find area of spherical triangle in a easiest way?
2. How to find the volume of Spherical tetrahedron! which is in $S^3$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would expect the answer to depend on the form in which the triangle and tetrahedron are given.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.2584 has a formula for the volume based on the dihedral angles of the tetrahedron. For the surface area, you could use the usual spherical excess formulas.